# Program Crashes with Qt QAbstractTableModel::index

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement a custom model in qt.

I have subclassed QAbstractTableModel into my own class. I have reimplemented the needed methods, but not the index method (as the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#index) say). columnCount() always returns 4 (there are a fixed number of columns) and rowCount returns the number of insterted rows.

My program looks something like this:

application.h

```
#include mymodel.h
class ContilasSimulator : public QApplication
{
public:
    Aplication(int argc, char *argv[]);
    void someFunction();
private:
    MyModel m_model;
    MainWindow m_window;
};
```

application.cpp

```
#include application.h
Application::Application(int argc, char *argv[]) : QApplication(argc,argv),
{
    m_window.setModel(&m_model);
}

void someFunction()
{
    //...
if (m_model.insertRows(0,2))
    {
        QModelIndex index = m_model.index(0,0); //this statement works fine
        index = m_model.index(1,0); // this statement also works fine
        index = m_model.index(0,5); //this statements return an invalid index (as expected)
        index = m_model.index(0,1); //the program crashes a few seconds after executing this line
        //other code...
}
```

The program crashes only after I have tried to get the m_model.index(0,1) line, but not immidiately (ie, the next few lines will execute, but a few seconds later the program crashes). When going line by line with my debugger, the program will crash either on the line after the probelm line, or a few lines later, depending on how fast I step through. I get this error message:

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 510
```

I cannot figure out why the program works fine when I am requesting an index of (0,0) and (1,0) but not (0,1). Nor can I figure out why it does not fail right away and instead takes a few seconds to fail. I am not doing anything with threads.

Any help on why I might have this problem or further debugging steps I can take would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Qt 5.5 with Qt Creator 3.4.2 compiling with mingw

Comment: I expect the bug is in `MyModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access invalid indexes... This is unspecified behavior... Some implementations of `qabstractitemmodel` will return an invalid index if the parameters are crazy. But it is not guaranteed..

What happen in this case is that the table model use a QList under the hood and don't bother doing range checks... which cause an out of bound access. I suspect out of bound accesses to be an [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), even if Qt doesn't say what it is.

Anyway it is wrong. **Access valid indexes only**. End of the story.